# WP_Query with custom post type search showing all results every time

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, search

I'm working on building a search form for some custom post type. Problem is, the search yields the same results every time, which is all posts of that custom type. Please advice:

Code:

Search form:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >  
  <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search DARPE">
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="darpe-entries"> 
    <input type="submit" alt="Search" value="Search">

  </form>
```

Search template:

```
 <div  class="row">
                    <?php
$the_query = new WP_Query('post_type=darpe-entries');

 if($the_query->have_posts()) : while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                    <div class="post-item col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div <?php post_class();?>>
                            <div class="blog-grid-item" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                                <div class="blog-grid-thumb">
                                    <span class="cat-blog"><?php the_category(', ') ?></span>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) {

                                            the_post_thumbnail(); 
                                            } else { ?>
                                                <img src="http://placehold.it/360x220" alt="">

                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="box-content-inner">
                                    <h4 class="blog-grid-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                                    <p class="blog-grid-meta small-text">
                                        <span><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></span>
                                        <?php _e(' With ', CORE_THEME_NAME ); ?>
                                        <span><?php comments_popup_link('No comments', '1 comment', '% comments', 'comments-link', 'Comments are closed'); ?></span>
                                    </p>
                                </div> <!-- /.box-content-inner -->
                            </div> <!-- /.blog-grid-item -->
                        </div> <!-- /.post-class -->
                    </div> <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
                    <?php endwhile; else : ?>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="widget-main">
                                    <div class="widget-inner">
                                        <p><?php _e( 'No posts found.', CORE_THEME_NAME ); ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    <?php endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Do not use a custom query on your search template. Use `pre_get_posts` to correctly alter the main query according to your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're passing your search query in your WP_Query args. To do this on a custom search page try the following:

Replace this:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query('post_type=darpe-entries');
```

With this:

```
global $query_string;

$query_args = explode("&", $query_string);
$search_query = array();

foreach($query_args as $key => $string) {
    $query_split = explode("=", $string);
    $search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1]);
}

$search_query['post_type'] = 'darpe-entries'; // your custom post type

$the_query = new WP_Query($search_query);
```

Comment: Don't use a custom query to alter the main query on the search page, use `pre_get_posts` instead to alter the main query :-)

Comment: Yep @PieterGoosen is right. I had my blinkers on :)

Comment: Thanks to both of you. It's working and I will try with pre_get_posts, too. Can you suggest a way to show results before user do his first search?